# WPF Popup Alternative

Tags: wpf, popup

I have a window with a popup that pops when an item in a listview is double clicked.
It centers to the main window and looks really nice floating there.
The problem is when the user moves the main window or selects another program, and the popup floats on top of other stuff.

I would like to have something like a popup, meaning that it floats on top of other elements in the window, but sticks with the main window when it moves (stays centered), and doesn't float on top of other programs.
Can I make a popup act like this, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It's in VB.Net 2010, and don't think Popup has .Owner as a property, and if I try setting `Window.GetWindow(Me).Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow` I get an error saying `Cannot set Owner property to itself.` So I'm not sure how to do this correctly.

Comment: Since this is the top hit on Google for "wpf popup floats over other applications". If you want to use a popup for other reasons, I just want to drop a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316139/popup-doesnt-lose-focus-and-close-until-ive-clicked-a-control-within-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that an [Adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) will fit your needs in this case better than a popup.  Adorners can float above your window, too.  There are a few differences, mainly that an adorner is bound to a UIElement (which include windows).

Comment: Do you know if an Adorner can be applied to an element after the fact? I'm trying to make this program pretty modular, so the listview that pops up the popup is part of a custom user control, which is embedded in a Page, which is inside a navigation Frame on the window. I would like to make it so that all I have to do is put the Adorner code inside of the user control and tell it to attach to the window. I could attach it to the user control, but I'm hoping to center it in the window.

Comment: Yes, they can be added and removed on the fly like popups.  For example, I wrote my own DataGrid and use an Adorner as the editing window for cells.  Make sure your Window has an AdornerLayer (I suggest adding one to your Xaml) and you can easily center the adorner in it.

Comment: Any good resources explaining the process? Apparently "AdornerLayer" is pretty ambiguous, without many good examples on the best way to use it. most examples are "put a dot on the corner of a textbox" and involve writing a class for each one. When this is done, I'll probably have over a dozen "popup" style controls, mostly containing a custom user control, and I'd prefer not to have to write a specific class for each one if I can help it. Popups are so easy to use, being able to design it in XAML and show it as needed. An adorner control with this kind of easy creation would be great.

Comment: I usually just add <AdornerLayer> inside my Window or top level Grid or whatever to ensure that one exists.  In some cases such as when I've used a control inside a Dialog, for some reason the layer isn't there.

Answer (score 5):

Popups will not move while the window is resized or moved. Because, Popups/Context menus are not the part of Visual Tree. You have to use [Adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) for this. I will suggest to read [this](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/06/21/wpf-adorners-part-1-ndash-what-are-adorners.aspx) four part series for a quick start on Adorner.

Comment: Do you know if an Adorner can be applied to an element after the fact? I'm trying to make this program pretty modular, so the listview that pops up the popup is part of a custom user control, which is embedded in a Page, which is inside a navigation Frame on the window. I would like to make it so that all I have to do is put the Adorner code inside of the user control and tell it to attach to the window. I could attach it to the user control, but I'm hoping to center it in the window.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use a third-party/open source (MS-PL) option, the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) has a [ChildWindow control](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow&referringTitle=Home).

It's technically not a separate window, but it appears to be a separate window to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to make Popups stop doing that in WPF

As an alternative, you can create a UserControl which acts like a Popup.

Usually I host the content section of the app along with the Popup within a Canvas control, and when IsPopupOpen gets changed to True I set the popup Visibility = Visible.

Comment: This may be the way to go, but I'm still not sure the best way to do it. The ListView is in a CustomUserControl, inside a Page, inside a Navigation Frame, inside the Window (which isn't the main window, in case that would have made it easier)

Comment: I could add a Canvas to the Page, but I'm not sure how to bubble up the command to open it from the UserControl

Comment: @AndyD273 I would add the popup to your top control (in this case, Window), and have a property in your ViewModel of `IsPopupOpen`. I would then setup an Event listener to listen for `ShowPopupEvent`s, and show the popup when that event gets raised. You could also pass in popup content as part of the ShowPopupEvent parameters.