# WPF open popup window and work on the main window while the popup is open

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF. In my application I have to show a chart in a popup window when the show chart button is clicked in the main window. While the popup is open and displaying, the user should be able to change the values in the main window so that the chart will automatically updates.

The issue is, how can I display the popup while the user work in the main window. The Window.ShowDialog() will not allow to work in the main window while the popup is open. And when I use the Window.Show(), when the focus is set to mainwindow, the popup goes to the back and the chart is not displayed.

How can I enable the user to work in the main window while the popup is displaying the content.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popup shouldn't be opened with `Window.ShowDialog()`, since that would make it modal (and you would not be able to return to the main window until it is closed.)

If you open the popup window with `Window.Show()`, you can tell the popup to stay on top of everything by setting `TopMost` to true on it.

```
var popup = new PopupWindow();
popup.Show();
popup.TopMost = true;
```

you could even pull back the focus to the main window afterward by calling `.Activate()` on that window.

Answer (score 2):

You could nest your chart in a Popup rather than in a Window and then launch it like this

```
<Button x:Name="button" Click="button_Click"/>
<Popup x:Name="popup" StaysOpen="true">
    <TextBlock Text="Clicked"/>
</Popup>

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!popup.IsOpen) popup.IsOpen = true; // Open it if it's not open
    else popup.IsOpen = false; // Close it if it's open
}
```

This [article](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/popup/) describes more of your options.

Alternatively, you could try starting your Windows in separate UI threads like this [article](https://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/) suggests. Something like this

```
<Button x:Name="button" Click="button_Click"/>

private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        MyWindow w = new MyWindow();
        w.Show();

        w.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
        w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}
```

The advantage of the popup approach is it's much simpler. One advantage of the multiple UI thread approach is that you could have a second, fully functioning, window not a popup.

An issue with both approaches is that when you move your main window your second window won't move with it. This being said, at least with the second window approach it's clearer that your second window is independent of your first than it is with the popup approach. Solutions to this problem include using an [adorner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/adorners-overview) as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585671/wpf-popup-alternative?rq=1) or setting aside a portion of your main window for "additional information" and then you could show/hide things like your chart by changing the visibility.

Comment: toggling the popup contains an error ;) you could also write it simpler as `popup.IsOpen = !popup.IsOpen;`.

Comment: While i think the threading example is rather complex for something like this, and best left alone (because of the added complexity, since OP wants to update the contents of their popup from the first UI thread), i agree on the solution with the actual `Popup` in xaml.

Comment: @TimothyGroote I know you could do popup.IsOpen = !popup.IsOpen; but I thought that it might be a little subtle and be missed. I agree, the popup is, almost certainly, the better solution in this case I just thought I'd present an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

if you show the popup on a separate thread it will not stop block your main window e.g.

```
public void MessageBoxShow(string Message)
{
    Thread errorMessageThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Message);
    });
    errorMessageThread.IsBackground = true;
    errorMessageThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: He wants to show a chart in the second window, you can't do that with a `MessageBox`.

Comment: I was using message box as an example, I was not supplying a complete solution

Comment: i contest how useful this is, because you are only calling the `show` method on another thread. additionally, this is about a `messagebox`, which has nothing to do with op's question. 
To clarify, i haven't tried this, but since WPF employs a main 'ui thread', the net result of this is likely only a little more overhead without actual gains.
I even think this could cause runtime errors due to attempting cross-thread access

Comment: is a message box not a form of pop up??? and I can assure you there is no run time error. but thanks for the vote down

Comment: @stuicidle yes, a message box is a form of pop up, but you cannot populate it with custom controls.
The reason for the downvote is the suggestion to gratuitously use threading without understanding the benefit gained and the price you pay for it. If you would launch the popup window from another thread, the default binding model would break for that popup since the model is updated from another thread (in the main window's thread). All property changes to the viewmodel would require a dispatcher invoke, even when using data binding.